# 404 Error while doing load test in JMeter

Tags: java

Continuously I am getting the 404 error while doing the load test with 150 users in JMeter for a web application. Out of 150 users some users getting passed and rest getting failed.

What is the reason behind this, your help will be highly appreciated.

Getting 404 error. Please help me in this issue. . .

Comment: How do you think we can find out what is wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.